# Mapped types based on enums with optional definition in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a mapped type `EventWithOptionalPayload`. Based on the chosen `Event`, the payload should have a specific interface.

However, in most cases, there should be no payload at all. How do I specify this in the type `Payload`?

I would like to prevent adding many lines with `undefined`. However, if I just remove those lines, typescript will tell me `Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'Payload'.ts(2536)`.

```js
export enum Event {
    EVENT_WITH_PAYLOAD_1,
    EVENT_WITH_PAYLOAD_2,
    EVENT_WITHOUT_PAYLOAD1,
    EVENT_WITHOUT_PAYLOAD2,
    // Most events will not have a payload
}

interface Payload1 {}
interface Payload2 {}

type Payload = {
    [Event.EVENT_WITH_PAYLOAD_1]: Payload1
    [Event.EVENT_WITH_PAYLOAD_2]: Payload2
    // [Event.EVENT_WITHOUT_PAYLOAD1]: undefined,
    // [Event.EVENT_WITHOUT_PAYLOAD2]: undefined,
    // many more cases of undefined 
}
 
type EventWithOptionalPayload<T extends Event> = {
    event: T;
    payload: Payload[T] // Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'Payload'.ts(2536)
}
```

Comment: Do you use EventEmitter or whatever?

Comment: You may be unterested to see how builtin Eventr are typed - `addEventListener<K extends keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: GlobalEventHandlers, ev: GlobalEventHandlersEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simple Intersection Type

Rather than using a mapped type you can use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) and default to undefined

```js
type Payload = {
    [Event.EVENT_WITH_PAYLOAD_1]: Payload1
    [Event.EVENT_WITH_PAYLOAD_2]: Payload2
} & Record<number, undefined>
```

[View this example on TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nap5pw)

Note how the key is `number`, this is a matching type implementation on `enums` and more info is available at [TypeScript: Handbook - Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html).

Consider the following problem that might arise

```js
type Valid = Payload[10] // undefined
```

However since you constrain the generic this appropriately causes an error:

```js
type Invalid = EventWithOptionalPayload<4> // Type '4' does not satisfy the constraint 'Event'.
```

This may be a non-issue depending on your usecase.

### Mapped Type

To resolve the problem of the above solution, we can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) with a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to generate all valid payloads.

```js
type EventsWithPayload = {
    [Event.EVENT_WITH_PAYLOAD_1]: Payload1
    [Event.EVENT_WITH_PAYLOAD_2]: Payload2
}

type Payload = {
  [T in Event]: T extends keyof EventsWithPayload ? EventsWithPayload[T] : undefined
}
```

[View this example on TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/W4Va7N)

Comment: Amazing! I went with the mapped type.